Chess Evaluation python
How can i get evaluation for position using python chess.engine?
I have a task: write adaptive chess bot for students using python
My idea: try to find out, how many best, excellent, good and bad moves average 1200ELO, 1500ELO etc. make per game and train a model, that gonna analyze first 20 moves of a game and set a Stockfish level, depending on the expected rating (for ex. 0-800 ELO - Stockfish lvl1, 800-1200 - stockfish lvl2 etc.).
I'm currently trying to get data for my model's train. My idea is: I'm comparing eval of the position after best possoble move (according to stockfish) and eval of the position after user's move. Question: how can i get this type of evaluation numbers (like -2.5 or +3.5)? Any methods?
Thank you for your answers!
here's my code^
                if move_obj in legal_moves:
                    premove_score = evaluate_position(board)
                    board.push(move_obj)
                    post_move_score = evaluate_position(board)
                    score_diff = post_move_score - premove_score

                    if score_diff >= -50:
                        first_line_moves += 1
                    elif -100 < score_diff <= -50:
                        second_line_moves += 1
                    elif -200 < score_diff <= -100:
                        third_line_moves += 1
                    else:
                        bad_moves += 1

                    total_moves += 1

                    board.pop()

                board.push_san(move_san)


I don't know how good the chess engines in Python are but there must be a few about. Find one that more or less agrees with Stockfish at some reasonable (short) time searching and can handle most of the classic chess puzzles. You appear to be working in centipawns (consider millipawns assuming that you are using integers rather than int16. I think you might get better results comparing Stockfish at full strength against the moves that the player actually played. aka Annotate mode in most chess apps. Obviously if player chooses that same move as Stockfish that counts as exact (worth counting).

Read here : https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html
